# Calling kotlin function from java class creates error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to call kotlin class function from Java class but getting error instead. I have added both kotlin and java code inside the java class. Below is the code and I am getting error while using context.

**KotlinClass:**

```
class TestDatabaseHandler(var context: Context?) :
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION)

{
    fun insertSerialNo(serialno: String)
    {
        val db=this.writableDatabase
        var cv=ContentValues()
    }
}
```

**JavaClass:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String serialno =123456;
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Test.class);
        intent.putExtra("serialno", serialno);

        //Below Four lines of Code Error in JavaClass
        var db= TestDatabaseHandler(this.applicationContext)
        db.insertSerialNo(serialno)
        //Java Conversion
        String db= new TestDatabaseHandler(this.context);
        db.insertSerialNo(serialno);

        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

**Error:**

1) Can't find symbol context

2) Can't resolve method insertSerialNo

Comment: you need to create Kotlin and Java code in separate files. Kotlin code goes in *.kt files, Java code - in *.java files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Below Four lines of Code Error in JavaClass
var db= TestDatabaseHandler(this.applicationContext)
db.insertSerialNo(serialno)
//Java Conversion
String db= new TestDatabaseHandler(this.context);
db.insertSerialNo(serialno);
```

Not counting comments:

The first two lines are in Kotlin. Java has no `var` syntax, and creating new instances requires the `new` keyword. Remove these lines.

The second two lines are the proper Java syntax for the Kotlin lines above. However, there is no such thing as `Activity.context`. Activity is already a Context. Just pass `this`, not `this.context`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.